# How one can show the joint probability density fucntion does not exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ be an unifrom random variable and $Y = X$.

**I am trying to show that the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ does not exist.**

Here is what I have gone so far.
Suppose there exists a function $f(x,y)$ such that 
$$
F(x,y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y) = \int_0^x \int_0^y f(t_1,t_2)dt_1dt_2.
$$
Note that $1 = f_X(t_1) = \int_0^1 f(t_1,t_2)dt_2$ 
and $1 = f_X(t_2) = f_Y(t_2) = \int_0^1 f(t_1,t_2)dt_1$.

Since $X = Y$, we have 
$$
F(x,y) = P(X \le \min\{x,y\}) = \int_0^{\min\{x,y\}} f_X(t_1)dt_1
= \int_0^{\min\{x,y\}} dt_1 = \min\{x,y\}.
$$

I was trying to show somehow $f(t_1,t_2) = 1$ based on $f_X(t_1)=1=f_Y(t_2)$ to draw a contradiction. But not sure how to do this.

Any comments/answers will be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Intuitively, you want to show that $(\partial^2/\partial x\partial y)(\min(x,y)$ is not a function.  Start off with $\partial/\partial x \min(x,y) = 1 $ if $x<y$ and $0$ if $x>y$.  Now when you take the derivative of this with respect to $y$ you get  0 everywhere except when $x=y$ where you get an infinitely large Dirac-delta like spike.  Such things exist, but they are not functions.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for your comment. I am aware of the result saying that if the partial derivative exists, it is the pdf. However, I am not aware of the converse. If you don't mind, could you point out a reference saying the converse is true (if it is true)?

Comment: I offer this as a symptom, not a proof.  The way to show there is no joint density is to show that the joint measure has a non-trivial singular component.  In your case, to calculate the area of a square's diagonal. It's zero, so the joint measure is singular with respect to $dxdy$, so no density function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to prove this.

Since $Y = X$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(X \le x, Y \le y) &= P(X \le x, Y \le y, X = Y) \\
&= \int_0^{\min\{x,y\}} \int_{t_2 = t_1} f(t_1,t_2) dt_2 dt_1 = \int_0^{\min\{x,y\}} 0\cdot dt_1 = 0
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Another way which is quite similar is to consider the set $A=\{(a,a):a\in [0,1]\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. This set is important because it is the set on which "the density would have to infinite in order to exist". Since $(X,Y)$ always lies in this set, we have
$$1
=P((X,Y)\in A)
=\iint_A f(x,y)dxdy
=\int_{x}^{x}\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy
=\int_{x}^{x}\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy=0$$